# Is there a powershell command to wait for the App uninstall job?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-addin

I have the following script to update my SharePoint app with the latest version but it always fails with the error:

> Install-SPApp : An instance of this App already exists at the
>   specified

when the app is already installed on the site. For SPSolutions I can wait on `while ($solution.JobExists)` **is there an equivalent for SharePoint Apps (.app)**?

```
#check if app already exists
$instances = Get-SPAppInstance -Web $siteCol
$instance = $instances | where {$_.Title -eq $file.BaseName}
if($instance -ne $null){
    Write-Host "Uninstalling app " $file.BaseName

    Uninstall-SPAppInstance -Identity $instance -Confirm:$false
    #need to wait here
}

Write-Host "Installing app " $file.BaseName
#install the app
$spapp = Import-SPAppPackage  –Path $file.FullName  –Site $siteCol  -Source ObjectModel -Confirm:$false
$newInstance = Install-SPApp –Web $siteCol -Identity $spapp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find the answer in this [MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ocarpen/archive/2012/08/15/scripts-to-install-update-or-uninstall-a-sharepoint-2013-app-with-powershell.aspx)

There is an `Update-SPAppInstance` method to be used when an app is already installed and then you can wait on the status of the AppInstance

```
while (($appInstance.Status -eq ([Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAppInstanceStatus]::Upgrading))
```